# com.danielsogl.cordova.deviceaccounts plugin not working in android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, hybrid

I used device accounts plugin to retrieve email id from user's android device.But this plugin returns nothing.Does anyone face similar issues with plugin?.

Here is the version,

cordova -v
7.1.0

ionic -v
3.20.0

npm -v
3.10.10

com.danielsogl.cordova.deviceaccounts 1.0.0 "Device Accounts".

```
      this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.GET_ACCOUNTS).then(
  result => {
    console.log('Has permission?', result.hasPermission);
    if (!result.hasPermission) {
      this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.GET_ACCOUNTS)
        .then(result => {
          console.log("success permission")
          this.deviceAccounts.getEmail()
            .then(accounts => {
              console.log("accounts got")
              console.log("accounts"+JSON.stringify(accounts));
            })
            .catch(error =>{
              console.error("getEmailsError"+error);
            });
        })
        .catch(err => console.log("error request permission"+err))
    }else{

       }
       });
```